# Android facebook sdk Profile feed

Tags: android, facebook

I am Facebook sdk newbie , i need to create a apps

I know how to post to wall, check in , get friend ,

But i don't know how to get Profile feed (Wall) and friend feed

Need to use Graph API ??

But i don't understand Graph API how to use

Comment: How to do Profile feed (Wall) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Facebook popup:

```
public void share(String day, String points)
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", XXXXXXXX);
    params.putString("caption", XXXXXXXX);
    params.putString("link", XXXXXXXX);
    params.putString("description",XXXXXXXX);
    facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish",params , new WallPostDialogListener());      
}

class WallPostDialogListener implements DialogListener 
{
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
    {
        if(data.facebook == true)
        {
            Log.e("SHARE",values.toString());
            if(values.getString("post_id")!=null)
            {

            }
        }

    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) 
    {
        Log.d("PostToWall","Facebook Error");
    }
    public void onError(DialogError e) 
    {
        Log.d("PostToWall","Dialog error");
    }
    public void onCancel() 
    {
        Log.d("PostToWall","Cancel");
    }
}
```

and without the Facebook dialog:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("name", XXXXXXXX);
parameters.putString("message", XXXXXXXX);
parameters.putString("link", XXXXXXXX);
response = facebook("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Try: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

For example:
(I don't know if this works)

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
response = facebook("me/feed", parameters, "GET");
JSONObject feeds = new JSONObject();
try
{
     feeds = new JSONObject(response);
}
catch(JSONException e)
{}
```

or:

```
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);  
mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", new FeedsRequestListener());

    private class FeedsRequestListener implements RequestListener 
    {           
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
            {
                    try 
                    {
                            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                            Log.e("OnComplete","JSONException");
                    }
                    catch (FacebookError e) 
                    {
                            Log.e("OnComplete","FacebookError");
                    }
            }
            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state)
            {
                    Log.e("FeedsRequest","onIOException " + e.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,Object state)
            {
                    Log.e("FeedsRequest","onFileNotFoundException " + e.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,Object state)
            {
                    Log.e("FeedsRequest","onMalformedURLException " + e.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state)
            {
                    Log.e("FeedsRequest","onFacebookError " + e.toString());
            }
    }
```

Comment: This is post to wall code??
i need diaplay News Feed and Profile Feed~~ 
By the way ,Thank you~!

Comment: Thank you very much But how to display in tableview or other view